# ViewWillAppear not called after clicking on alert of pushnotificatioin

Tags: ios, xcode, push-notification, viewwillappear

I'm newbie in iOS App Dev. I'm working on application having tabbar whose default tabindex is 2.
My problem is: When push notification arrive (in background state of app) after clicking on notification, my app open up on tab 2 and show an alertview. After clicking button of alertview I want to change the selectedTab to 3. Im writing below code in appDelegate in alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:, everything works fine.

```
    UIStoryboard* sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"story_iphone" bundle:nil];
    TabBarController * tb = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TabBarController"];
    [[tb.viewControllers  firstObject] viewWillAppear:YES];
    [tb viewWillAppear:YES];
    [tb setSelectedIndex:3];
    self.window.rootViewController = tb;
```

But im facing following problems:

1) ViewWillAppear of that VC (say vc1) is not called.

2)Also after pushing vc2 from vc1, viewWillAppear of VC2 is not called.

3) Poping back to VC1, ViewDidDisappear, ViewWillDisappear of VC2 is not called.

I have searched a lot but im unable to get where im lacking.
Please help me. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: use [self presentViewController:tb animated:YES];

Comment: I have to do from App delegate. and i think this code is not adequate in appdel.

Comment: Dude thats because you are instantiating a new tab bar controller and asking all the changes to be performed on the new one while leaving already loaded tab bar controller un affected. Whatever you do on new tab bar controller will not affect the UI or already loaded tab bar controller because they are different instances :)

Comment: @SandeepBhandari I tried using (UITabBarController*)self.window.rootViewController but that crashed my app.. :(

Comment: Whats the error ??

Comment: im testing with device. and getting ~ 
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

:( 
while debugging, pointer stuck on line and then crashes:[((UITabBarController*)self.window.rootViewController) setSelectedIndex:3];

Comment: How did you load tab bar controller ??

Comment: in appDel in didFinishLaunchingwithoptions 

 tabBar = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    [tabBar setDelegate:self];

and remember im getting in app from bakground state. after that i dont know about my view hiearchy.

Comment: @SandeepBhandari  in Splash screen VC im writting this.

UIStoryboard *objStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"story_iphone" bundle: nil];
        TabBarController* tabBarController = [objStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TabBarController"];
        tabBarController.selectedIndex = 2;
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:tabBarController animated:YES];

Comment: @SandeepBhandari can u give that code in obj c. 
i tried this. UINavigationController *navVc=(UINavigationController *)[[[UIApplication sharedApplication]keyWindow ]rootViewController];

        UITabBarController *tab =(UITabBarController *)[navVc.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
        tab.selectedIndex = 3;

is it correct?

Comment: yup :) Whats the issue ??? Did it crashed again ??

Comment: @SandeepBhandari yes :,(

when i debug for rootview it show something like UIApplicationRotationFollowingController

Comment: Can you simply print self.window.rootViewController in app delegate and print it here

Comment: @SandeepBhandari
po self.window.rootViewController
<UINavigationController: 0x13801fe00>

po [nav viewControllers];
<__NSArrayI 0x170633480>(
<SplashVC: 0x137d0e680>,
<TabBarController: 0x137e25b90>
)

Comment: Try my updated answer buddy :) You need to get the viewCOntroller at index 1 rather than 0 :) Thats all :)

Comment: Please read the suggestion and try modifying your code as per my suggestion as your current model is error prone :)

Comment: @SandeepBhandari  fixed it. Got the way I wanted. Thanks for helping me for so long..

Comment: why dont you make up your mind and accept one answer ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming UINavigationController is rootViewController of your app and you are pushing TabBarController to its navigation stack, this should work fine

**EDIT**

From your comments its clear that, you have tab bar controller in your navigation stack at position 1 rather than at 0 :) Hence now look for viewController at index 1.

```
(self.window?.rootViewController as! UINavigationController).viewControllers[1] as! UITabBarController).selectedIndex = your_index_value
```

**Suggestion :**

Though above mentioned solution works by the virtue that, tab bar controller is at index 1, but the position of tab bar controller in navigation stack may vary at some point if you decide to modify navigation stack itself.

Rather than hard coding the index value, what you can do is, in your app delegate have a variable named tab bar controller and make it public :) now once you create a tab bar controller before pushing it to navigation stack now hold the reference to it :)

Because app delegate is singleton and public property of it is accessible to all the viewControllers, now you can access it directly using app delegate.tabBarController :)

Now who cares where is it navigation stack :) Now you have the reference to the tab bar use it happily :) Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

You're not supposed to directly call `viewWillAppear`, or reload the tab bar controller since you have it already loaded with tab number 2 selected.

All you need to do is something like

```
[((UITabBarController*)self.window.rootViewController) setSelectedIndex:3];
```

in the alert handler.

Comment: but that crashes my app :(

Comment: @khush that's assuming your root view controller is the tab bar controller. If it is crashing then probably that's not the case. Look for the tab bar controller in your view hierarchy then call setSelectedIndex: on it.

Comment: how to do that??
I know thats a foolosh question. But i have never been on that topic.

Comment: @khush start by looking in your main storyboard to find which is your initial view controller? You may have the tab bar controller embedded within another controller in which case that's how you'd get to it. But you may want to consider making the tab bar controller the initial view controller if that's the main way the user is supposed to navigate your app.

Comment: my root view controller is navigatioin controller